# change file(image) input ajax can't post file

Tags: php, ajax, file, post

Ajax can not send files (jpg-png). I could not solve the problem.

form code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="img"> 
  <button id="post-img">update</button>
  <!-- input hidden !! -->
  <input type="file" name="img" id="a-img" style="visibility:hidden">
</label>
```

ajax:

```
$('#a-img').change(function(){
  var photo = $('form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url:'upload.php',
    data: photo,
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
   });
});
```

php code:

```
if($_FILES){
 echo "file ok";
}else{
 echo "no file"; 
}
```

callback : "no file";

Comment: you can not send files like this

Comment: file is image jpg-png-gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add id frm_send_img to the form.

```
<form action="upload.php" id="frm_send_img" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="img"> 
  <button id="post-img">update</button>
  <!-- input hidden !! -->
  <input type="file" name="img" id="a-img" style="visibility:hidden">
</label>
```

Change script like below.

```
 $('#a-img').change(function(){
            var photo = new FormData($("#frm_send_img")[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: photo,
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg)
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: e.preventDefault() .
 this -> $('button').click(function(e){e.preventDefault() } ??

Comment: I changed the button to span and working code

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
 $('#a-img').change(function(){
        var frmData = new FormData();
        frmData.append('file', $('#a-img')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            data: frmData,
        }).done(function (msg) {
          //logic after success
        });
```

You can access images on server as usual:

```
if (isset($_FILES["img"]["name"]) && $_FILES["img"]["name"] != "") {
     echo "image validation and uploading";
    }else{
     echo "no file uploaded"; 
    }
```

Comment: I just want to do when the selected img

Comment: console : Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: removed that line.

Comment: again  Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.